# USB webcam to composite video via Software?

Tags: usb, digital-logic, analog, software, conversion

I need a way to convert digital usb signals from a webcam into composite, analog output in real-time. Is there any software that could do this?

Comment: Need more info. Mainly, are you looking for a computer program to run on your existing computer? An embedded solution? You basically need a small embedded computer like a Via or Arm, A thin Client or Cell Phone, to process video to composite out. You'd be better off with just buying a composite video camera.

Comment: A [Raspberry Pi](http://www.raspberrypi.org/) has all the necessary hardware to do this, and probably most of the software required is also readily available.

Answer (score 2):

No. The digital usb signals carry data. You need to recover the data (MPEG video stream) transcode it to a relevant NTSC or PAL standard and generate the analog composite output. You can do the signal capture and transcoding in software, but  you need hardware for the output obviously.

Comment: Actually, you don't need much hardware beyond a DAC, as there are processors capable of synthesizing a video waveform in software.  And the source tends to be mjpeg rather than mpeg.

Comment: @ChrisStratton = In his defense, a DAC = hardware.